# How to setup clean ("virgin") win with VM Hyper-V?

Tags: windows, virtual-machine

I need a VM with Win on board I have carried out a small research in google and found out that win system offering such an option like from the box

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/virtualization/hyper-v-on-windows/quick-start/quick-create-virtual-machine

I went through all steps and got my windows on VM , but question is why it has `Visual Studio` and `Visual Studio Code` as a default installed apps?

[image]

Google chrome here is the browser that I installed.

I wanted this windows to be completely clear without any development tools and IDEs I was need it for test. Currently I am not sure that remove these apps will help because along with installation of VS others types of redistributive also were installing. So, I need to delete this VM Win and create it from the beginning, but question is - that I don't see an option to refuse of default app installation along with win.

So, question is - how to install win on VM completely clean without any other additional apps?

**EDIT**

After I tried to download tool from here https://www.microsoft.com/en-gb/software-download/windows10 and then I created `Win.iso` then I opened VM Hyper-V and chose there `Local installation source` where I provided path to just created `Win.iso` file.

Then I got this notification

[image]

and then this

[image]

It is not clear, Hyper-V has a option to load VM from iso, but then it ask to read iso from cd disk...

What am I missing here? I don't have CD on my PC and it is actually a remote PC that I don't even have a physical access to it

**EDIT2**

In my case I don't have Win with Edge option to chose as you can see in the link. These are only options I have

[image]

Comment: In step 2 of the link you provided, did you choose "Windows 10 dev environment" or "Windows 10 with Microsoft Edge"?

Comment: The trial VMs you linked to are meant for software development and are meant to be used on a trial basis not permanent use which means they cannot be customized.  Of course you can download and install Windows 10 on your own VM easily enough (requires a license).

Comment: @spikey_richie edited my question and added screenshot. It is weird, but I don't have an option to chose Win with Edge

Comment: @Ramhound edited my question, I tried to create iso file as described in tutorial (link provided) , but it doesn't work properly :(

Comment: On the _"Press any key to boot from CD or DVD"_ step, did you press any key?

Comment: @gronostaj , no. Looks like I shouldn't, right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For a **completely** clean install, you are best to start with a Windows 10 ISO file from https://www.microsoft.com/en-gb/software-download/windows10.

In the link you provided in the question, they are template ISO images with some applications pre-loaded.

Comment: I edited my question, could you please take a looks, maybe you know how to solve it

Comment: @AlekseyTimoshchenko you've asked a new question. Spikey_richie answered the question you asked. If you have a new question (which you do) you click the blue Ask A Question button at the top of the page and ask another.

Answer (score 2):

On the screen that says

> Press any key to boot from CD or DVD

you have to press any key to boot from the DVD.

Otherwise the ISO of a Windows DVD you've inserted into a virtual drive isn't used at all. You want to boot it to start the installation.

Comment: IIRC there is a time window of ~5 seconds in which any key must be pressed.

Comment: Where's the `any` key? :P

Comment: Thanks it works. But it is not obvious, it says `Press to boot from CD or DVD`, but it is actually neither CD or DVD. Anyway it works

Comment: @AlekseyTimoshchenko It is a DVD, just a virtual one. ISOs are images of CDs or DVDs. The Windows DVD ISO is "inserted" into a virtual DVD drive. The virtual machine doesn't know the drive is virtual. It behaves exactly like a physical drive would. You want the VM to boot that virtual DVD.

Comment: @gronostaj after I finished with installation I got another issue here - https://superuser.com/q/1612152/678484